# Using Grpc in Laravel, Docker, Undefined type 'Grpc\ChannelCredentials'

Tags: php, laravel, docker, grpc

After setting everything up to use grpc,
my `composer.json`:

```
require: {
    ...
    "grpc/grpc": "^1.34",
    "spiral/php-grpc": "^1.4",
    "spiral/roadrunner": "^1.9",
    ...
}
```

I create new client:

```
...
$client = new ExampleClient('localhost:9090',[
    'credentials' => \Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure(),
]);
...
```

in Docker, i enabled grpc, protobuf:

```
docker-php-ext-enable grpc
docker-php-ext-enable protobuf
```

i checked grpc and protobuf in docker enviroment, output:

```
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-grpc.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-protobuf.ini,
grpc
grpc support => enabled
grpc module version => 1.43.0
grpc.enable_fork_support => 0 => 0
grpc.grpc_trace => no value => no value
grpc.grpc_verbosity => no value => no value
grpc.log_filename => no value => no value
grpc.poll_strategy => no value => no value
protobuf
protobuf.keep_descriptor_pool_after_request => 0 => 0
```

but Grpc\ChannelCredentials not found

Thank for your support !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Grpc\ChannelCredentials` is added through the grpc extension (`grpc.so`), so you won't find the file for it.

Comment: thank for your support